# How to break the for loop only for this specific value

Tags: c++

I want to ask how i can break from a 'for' loop in c++ but only for a specigic value. For example

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
    {
       //extra code here...   
    }
}
```

Now I want to break the for loop if the value of `z = 2` but I want to break and the loop of `i`.
Something like this:

i -> 0 
z -> 0 
z -> 1 
// break the loop for both
i-> 1
z -> 0
.........

Can anyone help me ???

Comment: There's not an easy method of doing this, best option is to put this into a function and return at that point.

Comment: If your question is about C++, why did you also tag C#?

Comment: Why not just use the condition `z < 2`?

Comment: Did you really mean `i++` in both loops?

Comment: What are these `i-> 1` and `z -> 0` doing after the break? If you broke out of both loops, why do they change values? It seems to me you only want to break *one* loop.

Comment: i want to break the second of loop of j for the specific value. Then the first loop will continue normally.

Comment: For me it is really unclear what you asking if it is not breaking two loops at one time. In one place you say you want to break 2 loops, in another - one loop, in another - loop with unexistent `j` variable, in another - break two loops with continue after break... Please rewrite your question with more attention to the text.

Answer (score 3):

You may choose from a lot of variants.

1. Use special flag variable:

   ```
   bool success = false;
   for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   {
       for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
       {
           //extra code here...   
           success = true;
           break;
       }
       if (success) {
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use a return statement (but you may also need to rewrite your code appropriately):

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   {
       for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
       {
          //extra code here...
          return; //or return <something>;   
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use a `throw` but in my opinion this is not really a good practice:

   ```
   try {
       for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
       {
           for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
           {
              //extra code here...   
              throw <something>
           }
       }
   } catch (const excpttype& e) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. Use a `stop`-condition in loops:

   ```
   bool breakFor = false;        
   for (i = 0; i <= 3 && !breakFor; i++)
   {
       for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
       {
          //extra code here...   
          breakFor = true;
          break;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Use explicit assignment to break the loops:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   {
       for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
       {
          //extra code here...   
          i = 4;
          break;
       }
   }
   ```
6. Use `goto` statement:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   {
       for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
       {
          //extra code here...   
          goto afterLoop;
       }
   }

   afterLoop:
   // code
   ```

The best practice in my opinion is to use flag-variable or refactor this loops to be inside a separated function.

Comment: It could also done by leaving both loops with a `goto`.

Comment: Yes, but goto is old-school practice and many people dislike it. Also Can someone correct my answer - code wrapping does not work for me, I don't know why.

Comment: Don't use goto or throw. Just have an extra condition in the for loop per my answer.

Comment: Of course, in my personal opinion `goto` and `throw` is really bad to use.

Comment: I would also use the return option, it nicely wraps up all housekeeping.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: Edited, in (numbered) bullet, you have to indent one more time (8 spaces instead of 4).

Comment: `goto` is told to be malign for historical reasons. People overused it, so it became an "evil" construct. But using `goto` to exit loop like this one is probably the best and most clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

No need of additional variable.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   for (z = 0; z <= 6; z++)
   {
      //extra code here...   
      if (z == 2) {
            i = 4;
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Although breaking the loop in this way does not make any sense. Probably you need some additional condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (z = 0; z <= 6; z++)
    {
       //extra code here...   
       if (specificValue) 
       {
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    boolean condition=false;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
        {
           //extra code here...   

            if(z==2){

                condition=true;
                break;
            }

        }

        if(condition){

            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the middle of a for loop is just a normal condition so you can check more than just the value of the integer.  i.e.

```
var breakTheLoop = false;

for (i = 0; i <= 3 && !breakTheLoop; i++)
{
    for (z = 0; z <= 6 && !breakTheLoop; z++)
    {
       //extra code here...   
       if (specificValue) 
       {
           breakTheLoop = true;
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `!breakTheLoop` in second `for` is redundant.

Comment: True.  Just added it to be explicit for the purposes of teaching.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is quite easy: Just set a if-statement and breat if the value is 2(or some value...)

for example:

**CODE**

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (z = 0; z <= 6; i++)
    {
       if(z == 2)
        break;
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem! If not just write a comment and tell me your error. Then I will try to write some code example for you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increment `z` in your second loop, it keeps running "forever".

Here is one approach:

```
bool break_loop = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 3 && !break_loop; ++i)
{
  for (int z = 0; z <= 6 && !break_loop; ++z)
  {
    //extra code here...
    if (z == 2)
      break_loop = 1;
  }
}
```

Or you can do if statements in both loops and then `break` which I prefer.

```
bool break_loop = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
{
  for (int z = 0; z <= 6; ++z)
  {
    //extra code here...
    if (z == 2)
      break_loop = 1;
  }
  if (break_loop)
    break;
}
```

Comment: you should use `&&` to test for break_loop